# Is there a way to get font measurements from within a PCL (Portable Class Library)?

Tags: c#, fonts, portable-class-library, fontmetrics

I'm trying to find a way to get font measurements from within my PCL (Portable Class Library), however every resource I have come across to get font measurements seems to be platform specific.

Is this a limitation of the PCL to not support a *portable* way of retrieving font metrics?

And, if they have different ways of retrieving the metrics, does that mean that the metrics are different? That is, if I have Courier New 10 pt font, would the word **Hello** have a different width from a Windows desktop vs Windows Phone vs Windows RT application?

Comment: Yes, fonts are highly platform-specific.  Even on the same platform, a WPF font is a very different animal from a Winforms font.  So this just can't work.  Use a delegate if you have to so the host app can provide an implementation of whatever function you need.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you saying that the word **Hello** would actually take up a different amount of pixels (height, width, etc) on a Windows Form app, as opposed to a WPF app?

Comment: Certainly.  It isn't even consistent in a WPF app, backgrounder [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx).